# В maine при инициализации конструкторов возникают следующие ошибки(см. скриншот). Весь интернет облазил уже не знаю что делать

Tags: c++, ооп

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
struct Tovar
{
    int size;
    char name;
    int price;
};

class sklad
{
public:
    Tovar* data;
    int N;
    sklad(int p,int size);
    void vvod(int p, int price, int sum, char name);
    void vyvod(Tovar& x);
    void save(int sum);
    void res(int p, int sum);
    void head(char name, int price);
    ~sklad();
};

sklad::sklad(int p, int size)
{
    size = p;
    data = new Tovar[size];
}; 


sklad::~sklad()
{
    if (data)
        delete[] data;
}
void sklad::head(char name, int price)
{
    printf("%-15s    %-15s\n", "Товар", "Цена");
};

void sklad::vvod(int p, int price, int sum, char name)
{
    cout << "Введите количество товаров";
    cin >> p;
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
    {
        cin >> name >> price >> sum;
    }
};
void sklad::vyvod(Tovar&x)
{
    printf("%-22c %-15i\n", x.name, x.price);
};

void sklad::save(int sum)
{
    int xkol=0;
    Tovar* x;
    x = new Tovar[xkol];
    for(int i =0; i<xkol; i++)
        if ((data[i].price < sum) && (data[i].price==sum))
        {       
            xkol++;
            x = (Tovar*)realloc(data, xkol); 
        }
    FILE *f;
    fopen_s(&f, "Tovar.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(x, sizeof(Tovar), xkol, f);
    fclose(f);
    delete []x;
};

void sklad::res(int p, int sum)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
        if (data[i].price <= sum)
            vyvod(data[i]);
    cout << endl;
    save(p);
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int p;
    cout << "Введите количество товаров  " << endl;
    cin >> p;
    sklad A(p);
    int sum;
    cout << "Деньги покупателя  ";
    cin >> sum;

    A.res(p, sum);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас на скриншоте `sklad A;`, в тексте - `sklad A(p);`. Вы уж определитесь как-нибудь! И, кстати, конструктора **по умолчанию** у вас у `sklad` и в самом деле нет. Есть только конструктор от двух `int`'ов.

Answer (score 1):

```
sklad A(int,int);
```

у вас нет конструктора по-умолчанию

как добавить? в классе sklad(); и реализацию

Answer (score 0):

Ты забыл ключевое слово **this** для присваивания

Answer (score 0):

Конструктор по умолчанию - это такой конструктор класса, который не принимет никаких параметров. В 92-ой строке вы создаете экземпляр этого класса, вызывая конструктор по умолчанию (это происходит автоматически). Чтобы избежать ошибки вам следует либо создать конструктор по умолчанию,

```
class sklad {
public:
    ...
    sklad(int p, int size);
    sklad() {}
    ...
}
```

либо передавать параметры конструктору при создании класса в 92-ой строке.

```
sklad(число, число);
```